# What is wrong with my MergeSort recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, mergesort

I'm using `MergeSort` on a custom linked list `lines` where the Nodes have `String` data and I want the algorithm to sort the elements in the list according to how many non-space characters each String has.

Here is the method for counting the number of non-space characters in a Stringm (which is the datum of each Node). I'm pretty confident this works as it should.

```
public static int numberOfCharacters(Node line)
{
    return line.data.replaceAll(" ", "").length();
}
```

Here is the algorithm itself. It is invoked by `mergeSort(lines.head);`

```
public static Node mergeSort(Node list1)
{
    if (list1 == null || list1.next == null)
    {
        return list1;
    }

    Node list2 = split(list1);

    list1 = mergeSort(list1);
    list2 = mergeSort(list2);

    return merge(list1, list2);
}

public static final Node split(Node list1)
{
    Node list2 = list1.next;
    list1.next = list2.next;
    list2.next = split(list2.next);
    return list2;
}
```

NetBeans is telling me before I even compile that `split()` will recurse infinitely.

The error I'm getting is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: You don't have a breaking condition in your `split` method. The method will call itself until the `next` member of your Node is empty (i.e. `null`). Also, please fix your code format. This is just horrible to look at. ;)

Comment: @brimborium Didn't even notice the indentation. I hope it's better now. How should I break? Or rather, how would you break?

Comment: Well, that's already much better. Although I don't like this style of breaking as it is not that readable. But that is just my opinion. I'm fine with it as long as it's consistently formated. In case you wonder: I prefer the [Google Java Style](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javaguide.html).

Comment: Were you able to fix your recursion issue?

Comment: @brimborium I actually ended up making my linked list doubly linked and used selection sort. There are a number of ways I could have done this (including the built-in Java LinkedList class) but there were certain parameters I had to abide by. Thanks for the help.